# Storing images and calling them from MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, file-upload, mongoose

I have looked around online and gotten only a few methods to work in test code but never on my actual code. I am trying to let the user upload an image in .jpg and then I want to call on it later to be displayed. Here is what I got so far.

```
fs = require("fs");
multer= require("multer");

app.use(multer({ dest: "./uploads/:id",
 rename: function (fieldname, filename) {
 return filename;
 },
}));
```

Then to pull the file from the form I am using:

```
image: req.body.image
```

As for the code to put it into the DB I am not sure, this is what I came up with but not too sure on if it will work or not. I also am clueless where to put it into my larger route I already have for the rest of the form.

Here is the small code:

```
app.post("/api/photo",function(req,res){
 var Startup = new Startup();
 Startup.img.data = fs.readFileSync(req.files.userPhoto.path);
 Startup.img.contentType = "image/jpg";
 Startup.save();
});
```

And here is the working (other than image) route code for the rest of the form.

```
// CREATE add new startup to database
app.post("/startup-submit", function(req, res) {
   // Get data from form
  I create the variables here, removed as too much code and code for the image draw is above.    
   //Pass data through | Write better explaination later
   var newStartup = {about_startup: about_startup, social_media: social_media, about_founder: about_founder};
   Startup.create(newStartup, function(err, newlyCreatedStartup){
       if(err){
           console.log(err);
       } else {
           // Redirect back to show all page
           res.redirect("/startups");
       }
   });
});
```

I know the route paths on the small and large code don't line up but i was using that for testing.

How can I mesh and fix this code so that it will allow me to upload an image/file to my DB?

Then how would I call it to be an  src using EJS. Would it just be ">    This is the best I have came up with. I am sure it is far from right though.

Comment: Error in my post,  should be:

Would it just be <img src="<% startup.thing.image %>">

Answer (score 0):

Follow the [documentation](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#usage).

(1) `dest` is where you store your files. `./uploads/:id` does not look like a valid destination.

(2) Where did you get `rename` option?

(3) Don't store the actual image in the database. Just store the filename.

It should look more like

```
var fs = require("fs"),
    multer = require("multer");

var upload = multer({
    storage: multer.diskStorage({
        destination: function (req, file, cb) {
            // here is where you would add any extra logic to create directories
            // for where you will upload your file
            cb(null, './uploads')
        },
        filename: function (req, file, cb) {
            // here is where you would add any extra logic to rename your file
            cb(null, file.fieldname);
        }
    })
});

app.post("/api/photo", upload.single('fieldname'), function (req, res, next) {
    // at this point, the file should have been uploaded
    // you can get info about your file in req.file
    console.log(req.file);

    var startup = new Startup();
    startup.img.data = req.file.filename;
    startup.img.contentType = req.file.mimetype;
    startup.save(function (err) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        // send response
    });
});
```

You might find [fs-extra](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra) useful, particulary [fs.mkdirs()](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra/blob/master/docs/ensureDir.md) if you want to create directories e.g. `/this/path/does/not/exist`.